# Randomly Generate Variable Upon Page Load

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm trying to create a hangman game in JavaScript, however, I'm running into an issue of trying to get the names to randomly generate upon the page load. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Please see the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <p id='movie-title'></p>
  <footer>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

```
var movieTitles = [
  "Halloween",
  "Suspiria",
  "Audition",
  "Hereditary",
  "The Beyond",
  "The Evil Dead",
  "The Blair Witch Project"
];

function randomMovieTitle(movie) {
  return "Movie Title:"+ " " + movie;
}
document.getElementById("movie-title").innerHTML = randomMovieTitle("Halloween");
```

I have also tried putting

```
moviesToGuess = movieTitles[Math.floor(Math.random() * movieTitles.length)];
```

where 'Halloween' is in

```
document.getElementById("movie-title").innerHTML = randomMovieTitle("Halloween");
```

But I cannot get it to randomly generate and I have been trying to us

```
document.getElementById("movie-title").onload = function() {randomMovieTitle()};
```

for the page to load.

To get the page to randomly generate one of the movie titles upon page load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `Math.random` in the function call:

```js
var movieTitles = [
  "Halloween",
  "Suspiria",
  "Audition",
  "Hereditary",
  "The Beyond",
  "The Evil Dead",
  "The Blair Witch Project"
];

function randomMovieTitle(movie) {
  return "Movie Title: " + movie;
}
document.getElementById("movie-title").innerHTML = randomMovieTitle(movieTitles[Math.floor(Math.random() * movieTitles.length)]);
```

```html
<p id='movie-title'></p>
```

Press `Run code snippet` a few times to see it in action.